# how to join laravel model collections

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collections, model

I am trying to get into models/collections as opposed to straight sql calls in my controllers. I have 2 database tables.

1. tasks
2. resources

My Tasks table

| taskName | resourceId |
| --- | --- |
| someTask | 1 |
| task2 | 2 |

My Resources table

| resourceId | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |

in straight sql i would do

```
 $sel = "SELECT taskName,resources.resourceId,resources.name ";
 $from = "FROM tasks,resources ";
 $where = "WHERE tasks.resourceId=resources.resourceId";
```

and get

```
someTask,1,abc
task2,2,xyz
```

how can I do this using models, collections?

I know you all like code I have tried, but I am not sure to where to even begin.  I can do the basic  $x = tasks::all() stuff...

**Edit

tasks.php

```
class tasks extends Model
{
    /**
 * The database connection that should be used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
    protected $table = 'tasks';
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
}
```

resources.php

```
class resources extends Model
{

protected $table = 'resources';
protected $connection = 'mysql';
}
```

Comment: Have you created the models `Task` and `Resource`?

Comment: yes, those are extremely basic as this point. ill add them above

Comment: did you define the relations between the two models ?

Comment: im reading about return $this->hasMany('App\Models\tasks');  type stuff in each of the models, is that the route I need to go?

Comment: Depends on the relationship between `Task` and `Resource` (note: Model names are `PascalCase` and Singular, so `Task` and `Resource`, not `tasks` or `resources`). If it's one-to-one / one-to-many, it's a `belongsTo()` / `hasOne()` or `hasMany()`, a many-to-many requires a `pivot` table, and uses `belongsToMany()`. All documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: this looks like its exactly what im looking for.  thank you.

Comment: No problem! When all is said and done, you can do something like `$tasks = Task::with('resources')->get()` to load all `tasks` rows from the database, and each would have `->resources` available (or reversed, like `$resources = Resource::with('tasks')->get()`, whatever is appropriate). Note: `->get()` (or `::all()`) returns _multiple_ Models as a Collection, while `->first()` (or `::find($id)`) returns a single Model, or `null` if it can't find one. Play with some Model queries to get an idea of how it all works, and happy coding! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class tasks extends Model
{
  
    public function resource()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(resources::class,''resourceId','resourceId');
    }
}

$tasks =tasks::with('resource')->get();
        
    foreach($tasks as $task)
    {
        echo $task->taskName.' '.$task->resourceId.' '.$task->resource->Name;
    }
```

Comment: this was where i was headed....i think!

Comment: Do not hesitate to add some explanation ..